# "everyone knew it was a joke" vs. "everyone knows it was a joke"

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

In my exercise book, I've found a quite confusing task. In the text, the 2012 Olympics ceremony is described.

> *One part of the ceremony appeared to show the Queen parachuting into the stadium. This has helped make her more popular than ever. Of course, she didn't really jump from a helicopter. Everyone ________ (know) it was a joke.*

The key states that **knew** is the right answer and I guess it is due to the sequence of tenses. But I am wondering if it is correct to use **knows** in such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Everyone knew** suggests that only the people who were present at the event or watching it at home knew that it was a joke. **Everyone knows** would suggest that everyone in the entire world today (at this moment) knows that the Queen parachuting into the stadium was a joke. In other words, this piece of knowledge must be as factual and well-known as the fact that there have been two world wars or that there is somewhere on this planet a country called Canada. At least, that's what it would sound like.

As you can see, they actually both make sense from a grammatical standpoint. Therefore, this is not really a verb-tense problem, but a semantic one. Of the two possible answers, you just need to pick the one that you think better fits the semantics of the story. Which one would it be? Of course, you should go for *everyone knew* because I'm pretty sure that most people in the world, myself included, have never heard of this joke and absolutely have no idea what was happening at that ceremony.